# INSERT INTO SELECT executed query but did not insert data to the database

Tags: vb.net

Hi I am working on this query to add existing records to the same database but different data specified. This is the query

```
Public Sub autoEnroll_by_Semester()
    'this is the connection string which is
    'in the enrollment_conn variable Data Source=192.168.254.108,1433;Network Library=DBMSSOCN;Initial Catalog = GEARS;User ID =user123;Password = user123"

    Try
        If MsgBox("Do you want to proceed with auto enrolling the records?" & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & "Please double check before proceeding!", vbInformation + MsgBoxStyle.YesNo) = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then
            enrollment_conn.Open()
            command = New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO dbo.Enrollees(RegistrationID,Track,Strand,Specialization_TVL,Grade,Section,Semester,School_Year,Transferee,Transferee_School,Transferee_Address,Transferred,Transfer_Type,Establishment_School,Date_Of_Transfer,Dropped,Date_Dropped,Regular,Gen_Average,Enrolled,Date_Enrolled) " & _
                                     "SELECT RegistrationID,Track,Strand,Specialization_TVL,Grade,Section,'" & Auto_Enroll_Semester.Specify_Cbx_semester.Text & "',School_Year,Transferee,Transferee_School,Transferee_Address,Transferred,Transfer_Type,Establishment_School,Date_Of_Transfer,Dropped,Date_Dropped,Regular,Gen_Average,Enrolled,'" & Auto_Enroll_Semester.Specify_Date_enrolled.Text & "'" & _
                                     " FROM dbo.Enrollees " & _
                                     "WHERE Enrolled='Yes' AND Semester='" & Auto_Enroll_Semester.Select_Cbx_semester.Text & "' AND School_Year='" & Auto_Enroll_Semester.Select_Cbx_schoolyear.Text & "' AND Section='Einstein'", enrollment_conn)
            command.ExecuteNonQuery()
            MsgBox("New records have been inserted.. Please check enrollees list", vbInformation)
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message, vbExclamation)
    Finally
        command.Parameters.Clear()
        enrollment_conn.Close()
    End Try
End Sub
```

After I executed the query it executes but no new records.. My question is how can I make that work or it does not inserts record when you use controls as the basis for your values? Is there any other possible way to do this? Thanks

This is the result of the trace.writeline:
INSERT INTO dbo.Enrollees(RegistrationID,Track,Strand,Specialization_TVL,Grade,Section,Semester,School_Year,Transferee,Transferee_School,Transferee_Address,Transferred,Transfer_Type,Establishment_School,Date_Of_Transfer,Dropped,Date_Dropped,Regular,Gen_Average,Enrolled,Date_Enrolled) SELECT RegistrationID,Track,Strand,Specialization_TVL,Grade,Section,'12',School_Year,Transferee,Transferee_School,Transferee_Address,Transferred,Transfer_Type,Establishment_School,Date_Of_Transfer,Dropped,Date_Dropped,Regular,Gen_Average,Enrolled,'10/30/2018' FROM dbo.Enrollees WHERE Enrolled='Yes' AND Semester='11' AND School_Year='2018-2019' AND Section='Einstein';

Comment: What DBMS are you using? Please show what you have tried so we can help. Right now from that query you are not using parameters, IMHO you should be...

Comment: Hi I am using T-SQL as my database..

Comment: I've tried inserting records coming from table A to table A with 2 columns that has a different value so that it would be different after the insertion. In my query above, I've included controls to select the data. When I tried to execute nothing happens and when I looked at the table no data was inserted. If I run that query using MSSMS it executes and returns rows. I just wanted to execute that in VB.NET. Btw I'm using VB.NET 2010

Comment: Oh sorry SSMS is the DBMS

Comment: Again, *Please show what you have tried so we can help*...

Comment: SSMS is not a database either. SQL Server is the database.  SQL Server Management Studio is, as the name suggests, an application for managing SQL Server databases.  Show us the VB code you used to connect to the database and execute this SQL code.  That includes the connection string you used.  My first guess is that this is a local MDF data file and you're either looking in the wrong database or the right database at the wrong time.  It's a very common problem. We shouldn't have to guess though. You need to provide ALL the relevant information.

Comment: Don't put that much code in a comment. Please edit your question and add the code there. The edit button is between share and flag under the vb.net tag.

Comment: Okay didn't think of that..

Comment: Log the SQL statement to debug or Trace output `dim sSQL as string = "INSERT ..... statements";  Trace.WriteLine(sSQL)`, review in "Immediate Window". then run just the select part in SSMS and see if you get the desired results going to the insert statement.
A lot of the time the parameters are not outputted as expected .. also I concur with Codexer mentioned -- you should use Parameters to prevent SQL injection attacks and other fuzzy cases that can occur because of.

Answer (score 0):

It is now working... The problem was a logical error.. The value in the where semester was invalid and may cause the select statement to fail selecting the records.. Thank you everyone for your help.. This case is now closed.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is with your SQL statement. The first one is the problematic one - it doesn't make much sense. Your saying, "I want you to put a new record in, with these fields having their value supplied", but then you didn't actually supply the values.

i.e.

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Enrollees(...)
```

should be written:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Enrollees(...) VALUES (...);
```

In other words, for your insert statement to actually mean something you must supply the actual values the record will have for all those fields.

As for your query, the second part of your SQL, it looks fine. Just add the values to the INSERT INTO statement above. Remember to add the semi-colon too.

Comment: Thank you for answering the question but the INSERT INTO SELECT statement does not need the VALUES keyword.